# Why PostgreSQL json_agg() function does not return an empty array?

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm returning a JSON array from a PostgreSQL request with the `json_agg` function. However, when no row is found, `json_agg` returns an empty string instead of an empty JSON array `[]` (square brackets are mandatory if I understand [json.org](http://json.org)).

For example:

```
SELECT json_agg(t.*) FROM (SELECT 'test' AS mycol WHERE 1 = 2) AS t ;
```

returns an empty string, whereas the same command with '1 = 1' returns a valid JSON array (tested with PostgreSQL 9.5).

Any idea?

Comment: `where 1=2` will never return any rows and `where 1=1` will return all rows. Of course the results are different. Why exactly do you find that surprising?

Comment: As explained in the question, IMHO `json_agg` should return a valid JSON array (i.e. `[]`)  when no row is selected. Instead, `json_agg`returns an empty string.

Comment: It returns `NULL` not an empty string. And this behavior [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html): "*It should be noted that except for count, these functions return a null value when no rows are selected*". If you don't want that, use `coalesce()`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the doc!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`json_agg` returns null from an empty set:

```
select json_agg(t.*) is null
from (select 'test' as mycol where 1 = 2) t ;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

If you want an empty json array `coalesce` it:

```
select coalesce(json_agg(t.*), '[]'::json)
from (select 'test' as mycol where 1 = 2) t ;
 coalesce 
----------
 []
```

Comment: Works fine on 9.6