# Any workarounds to use aggregators inside of another aggregators (aggregate functions)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables: `server`, `channel`, `subscriptions`. They're related **One to Many**; in one `server` can be many `channels`, in one `channel` can be many `subscriptions`.

In the past, I was just aggregating all the `subscriptions` that were corresponding to a `server`, so:

```sql
SELECT server.id, json_agg(
  json_build_object(
    'channel_id', subscription.channel_id,
    'subscription_staff1', subscription.subscription_staff1,
    'subscription_staff2', subscription.subscription_staff2,
    'subscription_staff3', subscription.subscription_staff3,
  )
) AS subscriptions
FROM subscription LEFT JOIN channel ON channel.id = channel_id LEFT JOIN server ON server.id = server_id
GROUP BY server.id
```

The response would be:

[image: Response]

Notice how there's 3 identical `channel_id`'s?

```json
[
  {
    "channel_id": 795430198983655400,
    "subscription_staff1": 11123,
    "subscription_staff2": "g",
    "subscription_staff3": false
  },
  {
    "channel_id": 795430198983655400,
    "subscription_staff1": 215256291,
    "subscription_staff2": "u",
    "subscription_staff3": false
  },
  {
    "channel_id": 795430198983655400,
    "subscription_staff1": 540230324,
    "subscription_staff2": "u",
    "subscription_staff3": false
  }
]
```

So it could just be smth like this:

```json
[
  {
    "channel_id": 795430198983655400,
    "subscriptions": [
      {
        "subscription_staff1": 11123,
        "subscription_staff2": "g",
        "subscription_staff3": false
      },
      {
        "subscription_staff1": 215256291,
        "subscription_staff2": "u",
        "subscription_staff3": false
      },
      {
        "subscription_staff1": 540230324,
        "subscription_staff2": "u",
        "subscription_staff3": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried doing json_agg() inside of another json_agg, but this clearly would not work just after looking at syntax.
`ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested`

So, any workarounds to this? Or am I doing this totally wrong and there is a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate on two levels: first get the subscriptions per channel into one array, then aggregate that by server

```
SELECT server.id, 
       jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('channel_id', channel_id, 
                                    'subscriptions', s.subscriptions))
FROM (
  SELECT sb.channel_id, 
         jsonb_agg(json_build_object('subscription_staff1', sb.subscription_staff1,
                                     'subscription_staff2', sb.subscription_staff2,
                                     'subscription_staff3', sb.subscription_staff3,
                                     )) as subscriptions
  FROM subscription sb
  GROUP by sb.channel_id
) s 
  LEFT JOIN channel ON channel.id = channel_id 
  LEFT JOIN server ON server.id = server_id
GROUP BY server.id;
```

Depending on the other columns of the `subscription` table you could maybe simplify the `jsonb_build_object()` part to: `jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(sb) - 'channel_id')  as subscriptions` - but that will include all columns of the `subscription` table (excluding channel_id) not only the three staff columns.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed.
Think you have a typo: subscriptions were aggregating to an array called `channel_id`. Modified a bit:
`SELECT server.id, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('channel_id', channel_id, 'subscriptions', s.subscriptions))`

Comment: Hey. Sorry to bother, but is there any way to retrieve empty array if there's no `channel` for `server`? I tried `coalesce(json_agg(...), '[]'::json)` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922340/why-postgresql-json-agg-function-does-not-return-an-empty-array), but this doesn't do anything